# Is it possible in Jquery detect the end of another script?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to ask a question about Jquery/javascript

My application have a jquery in background and I need to take the control when this script ends.

Is it possible, in Jquery , to detect the end of another script?
Is ir   [.promise](http://api.jquery.com/promise/)   a solution?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible, but what is in the other script? Do you have access to that?

Comment: JavaScript cannot detect something unless you use a timer or a callback function, both requiring you to modify the source code.

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is easy if the other script is entirely synchronous (no ajax, no timeout, not on `jQuery.ready()` or similar event).  In that scenario, simply placing your script after the other one in the page will suffice.

That's about all I can answer without more specifics.